# Manually fire Django 1.3's traceback/exception log

Tags: django

I'm using djutils's async decorator, which has the nasty side effect of not sending traceback emails when an exception is raised, since it runs on a separate thread.

It does, however, have the following place to put a logger.

```
def worker_thread():
    while 1:
        func, args, kwargs = queue.get()
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except: 
            pass # <-- log error here
        finally:
            queue.task_done()
```

I've confirmed this will work, but even with the try/except removed, it won't trip Django's traceback logger.

While it'd be pretty easy to tell it to write to a db/file on exception, I'd really like it to send a regular traceback as defined in settings. How can I do that?

**Edit:** answer seems to involve django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler - but I'm having a hard time finding an example.

**Edit 2:** Here's my current (99% likely to be wrong) attempt.

```
from django.utils.log import AdminEmailHandler
def worker_thread():
    while 1:
        func, args, kwargs = queue.get()
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            import logging
            from django.conf import settings
            print settings.EMAIL_HOST
            logger = logging.getLogger("async.logger")
            logger.exception("Async exploded")
            AdminEmailHandler
            pass # <-- log error here
        finally:
            queue.task_done()
```

Comment: did you try to just log the error as shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/ (emails are sent by the logging framework)

Comment: I've tried this:

  import logging;
  logger = logging.getLogger("async.logger");
  logger.exception("Async exploded");

Which does fire, but doesn't appear to do anything. And I'll be the first to admit that I'm probably implementing it wrong.

Comment: do you have the correct email settings (such as EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, etc) in your settings.py?

Comment: Yes. Outside of the async environment, this works exactly as it should. Since async runs on a separate thread (it's not a, doesn't have middleware, etc.) the default behavior doesn't kick in.

Comment: if you import settings and output your settings.EMAIL_HOST whatever to console from this method does it show the right values? does it find the logger? you said that logger.exception fires, then it reads settings correctly and finds the logger. right? basically, you need to debug this.

Comment: Yes, settings.EMAIL_HOST and the like show up correctly.

Comment: I should rephrase "fires." I have the object, I try to use it, it doesn't throw an error, and nothing seems to happen. I'll edit the question.

Comment: does the same logger work outside this asynchronous method?

Answer (score 3):

first, configure your logging settings i settings.py:

```
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'handlers': {
            'mail_admins': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'myproject': {
                'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                'level': 'INFO',
                'propagate': True,
            },
            'django.request': {
                'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True,
            },
        }
    }
```

from now, all loggers which starts with 'myproject' should use AdminEmailHandler
your code should look like this:

```
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger('myproject.optional.path')
    # example
    # logger = logging.getLogger('myprojects.myapp.views')
    def worker_thread():
        while 1:
            func, args, kwargs = queue.get()
            try:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                logger.exception("Async exploded")
            finally:
                queue.task_done()
```